# Converting a list of tuples into a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, iteration

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
[
('a', 1),
('a', 2),
('a', 3),
('b', 1),
('b', 2),
('c', 1),
]
```

I want to iterate through this keying by the first item, so, for example, I could print something like this:

```
a 1 2 3
b 1 2
c 1
```

How would I go about doing this without keeping an item to track whether the first item is the same as I loop around the tuples? This feels rather messy (plus I have to sort the list to start with)...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
l = [
('a', 1),
('a', 2),
('a', 3),
('b', 1),
('b', 2),
('c', 1),
]

d = {}
for x, y in l:
    d.setdefault(x, []).append(y)
print d
```

produces:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [1], 'b': [1, 2]}
```

Answer (score 39):

Slightly simpler...

```py
from collections import defaultdict

fq = defaultdict(list)
for n, v in myList:
    fq[n].append(v)
    
print(fq) # defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [1], 'b': [1, 2]})
```

Comment: *defaultdict* is definitely the way to go on this. In fact, if you take a look at the example in the docs it is remarkably similar to this problem - http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

Answer (score 11):

A solution using groupby

```
from itertools import groupby
l = [('a',1), ('a', 2),('a', 3),('b', 1),('b', 2),('c', 1),]
[(label, [v for l,v in value]) for (label, value) in groupby(l, lambda x:x[0])]
```

Output:

```
[('a', [1, 2, 3]), ('b', [1, 2]), ('c', [1])]
```

`groupby(l, lambda x:x[0])` gives you an iterator that contains

```
['a', [('a', 1), ...], c, [('c', 1)], ...]
```

Comment: You should probably mention that you need a sorted list for this (or use groupby(sorted(l),.. )for this to work.  The data given looks sorted, but the question mentions "(plus I have to sort the list to start with)..." so I'm not sure you can rely on this.

Answer (score 3):

I would just do the basic

```
answer = {}
for key, value in list_of_tuples:
  if key in answer:
    answer[key].append(value)
  else:
    answer[key] = [value]
```

If it's this short, why use anything complicated. Of course if you don't mind using setdefault that's okay too.

Answer (score 3):

#### Print list of tuples grouping by the first item

This answer is based on [the @gommen one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261655/converting-a-list-of-tuples-into-a-dict-in-python/261766#261766).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from itertools import groupby
from operator  import itemgetter

L = [
('a', 1),
('a', 2),
('a', 3),
('b', 1),
('b', 2),
('c', 1),
]

key = itemgetter(0)
L.sort(key=key) #NOTE: use `L.sort()` if you'd like second items to be sorted too
for k, group in groupby(L, key=key):
    print k, ' '.join(str(item[1]) for item in group)
```

Output:

```
a 1 2 3
b 1 2
c 1
```