# Count Duplicate URLs, fastest method possible

Tags: text-processing

I'm still working with this huge list of URLs, all the help I have received has been great.

At the moment I have the list looking like this (17000 URLs though):

- `http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1`
- `http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=3`
- `http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=2`
- `http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1`
- `http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=2`
- `http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=3`
- `http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=3`

I can filter out the duplicates no problem with a couple of methods, awk etc.  What I am really looking to do it take out the duplicate URLs but at the same time taking a count of how many times the URL exists in the list and printing the count next to the URL with a pipe separator.  After processing the list it should look like this:

| url | count |
| --- | --- |
| `http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1` | 2 |
| `http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=2` | 2 |
| `http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=3` | 3 |

What method would be the fastest way to achieve this?

Comment: All previous questions from this user were Python -- I assumed this one was Python also.  I put [python] on the question for that reason.

Comment: And I deleted it because it's not in the question and I didn't know this user has only asked about Python.

Comment: I was asking in general, any method would be fine, I am interested in seeing different approaches, all are very good :)

Comment: I've added `language-agnostic` tag and deleted `unix`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you're going to do this over and over again?  If not, then "fastest" as in fastest to implement is probably

```
sort </file/of/urls | uniq --count | awk '{ print $2, " | ", $1}'
```

(not tested, I'm not near a UNIX command line)

Answer (score 5):

This is probably as fast as you can get without writing code.

```
    $ cat foo.txt
    http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1
    http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=3
    http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=2
    http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1
    http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=2
    http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=3
    http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=3
    $ sort foo.txt | uniq -c
          2 http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1
          2 http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=2
          3 http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=3
```

Did a bit of testing, and it's not particularly fast, although for 17k it'll take little more than 1 second (on a loaded P4 2.8Ghz machine)

```
$ wc -l foo.txt
174955 foo.txt
vinko@mithril:~/i3media/2008/product/Pending$ time sort foo.txt | uniq -c
  54482 http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1
  48212 http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=2
  72261 http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=3

real    0m23.534s
user    0m16.817s
sys     0m0.084s

$ wc -l foo.txt
14955 foo.txt
$ time sort foo.txt | uniq -c
   4233 http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1
   4290 http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=2
   6432 http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=3

real    0m1.349s
user    0m1.216s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Although O() wins the game hands down, as usual. Tested S.Lott's solution and

```
$ cat pythoncount.py
from collections import defaultdict
myFile = open( "foo.txt", "ru" )
fq= defaultdict( int )
for n in myFile:
    fq[n] += 1
for n in fq.items():
    print "%s|%s" % (n[0].strip(),n[1])

$ wc -l foo.txt
14955 foo.txt

$ time python pythoncount.py
http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=2|4290
http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1|4233
http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=3|6432

real    0m0.072s
user    0m0.028s
sys     0m0.012s

$ wc -l foo.txt
1778955 foo.txt

$ time python pythoncount.py
http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=2|504762
http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1|517557
http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=3|756636

real    0m2.718s
user    0m2.440s
sys     0m0.072s
```

Comment: Could you test my solution too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264930/#297512

Answer (score 3):

In perl

[disclaimer: not able to test this code at the moment]

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    $occurences{$_}++;
}
foreach $url (sort keys %occurences) {
    printf "%s|%d\n", $url, $occurences{$url};
}
```

Comment: works. cat foo.txt | perlcount.pl . It's a tiny bit faster than the equivalent python's solution according to my testing

Comment: It is the fastest (as in "time it takes") so far. It is 3 times faster then the nearest competitor. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264930/#297512

Answer (score 2):

See [Converting a list of tuples into a dict in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261655/converting-a-list-of-tuples-into-a-dict-in-python).

Essentially, you're doing the same thing with an int instead of a list.

This may be faster than the system sort because it's O(n).  However, it's also Python, not C.

```
from collections import defaultdict
myFile = open( "urlFile", "ru" )
fq= defaultdict( int )
for n in myFile:
    fq[n] += 1

for url, count in fq.iteritems():
    print url.rstrip(), "|", count
```

On my little Dell D830, this processes 17000 URL's in 0.015 seconds.

Comment: Dual core.  No background load.  Also, I ran it a few times to get an average over 10 runs: 0.015 is worst-case, first time.  After that, I guess cache is loaded and it gets faster.  Average is 0.0125.

Comment: Added printing part of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version in Python:

```
import fileinput, itertools

urls = sorted(fileinput.input())
for url, sameurls in itertools.groupby(urls):
    print url.rstrip(), "|", sum(1 for _ in sameurls)
```

Example:

```
$ cat foo.txt
http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1
http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=3
http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=2
http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1
http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=2
http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=3
http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=3

$ python countuniq.py foo.txt
http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=1 | 2
http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=2 | 2
http://www.example.com/page?CONTENT_ITEM_ID=3 | 3
```

Performance:

```
C:\> timethis "sort urls17000.txt|uniq -c"
...
TimeThis :  Elapsed Time :  00:00:00.688

C:\> timethis python countuniq.py urls17000.txt
...
TimeThis :  Elapsed Time :  00:00:00.625

C:\> timethis python slott.py urls17000.txt
...
TimeThis :  Elapsed Time :  00:00:00.562

C:\> timethis perl toolkit.pl urls17000.txt
...
TimeThis :  Elapsed Time :  00:00:00.187
```

**Conclusion**: All solutions are under 1 second. The pipe is the slowest, [S.Lott's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264930/count-duplicate-urls-fastest-method-possible#264942) is faster then the above python's version and [toolkit's Perl solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264930/count-duplicate-urls-fastest-method-possible#264969) is the fastest.

---

```
C:\> timethis perl toolkit.pl urls1778955.txt
...
TimeThis :  Elapsed Time :  00:00:17.656

C:\> timethis "sort urls1778955.txt|uniq -c"
...
TimeThis :  Elapsed Time :  00:01:54.234

$ wc urls1778955.txt
1778955  1778955 81831930 urls1778955.txt
```

Hashing beats sorting for a large number of URLs.

Comment: The relative distance is huge, Perl takes a third of the time, of the next fastest competitor.