# Convert a list of tuples with repeated keys to a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have an association `list` with repeated keys:

```
l = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

and I want a `dict` with `list` values:

```
d = {1: [2, 3], 2: [3, 4]}
```

Can I do better than:

```
for (x,y) in l:
  try:
    z = d[x]
  except KeyError:
    z = d[x] = list()
  z.append(y)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a list of tuples into a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261655/converting-a-list-of-tuples-into-a-dict)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`dict.setdefault()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to provide a default empty list for missing keys:

```
for x, y in l:
    d.setdefault(x, []).append(y)
```

or you could use a [`defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to create empty lists for missing keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for x, y in l:
    d[x].append(y)
```

but to switch off the auto-vivication behaviour you'd have to set the `default_factory` attribute to `None`:

```
d.default_factory = None  # switch off creating new lists
```

Comment: how do you manage to see my questions _seconds_ after it is posted? :-)

Comment: @sds It is called *Ninja* vision

Comment: @sds: I wrote up my approach in [How do active answerers find questions to answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254603)

Comment: is there a faster way to do it using comprehensions?

Comment: @srcolinas: no, because a list comprehension can't group based on keys, not without sorting first (at which point you can use `itertools.groupby()`). Sorting will make it slower (moving from O(N) to O(NlogN)). List comprehensions are not a magic speed bullet, by the way.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k, v in l:
    d[k].append(v)
```