# How to filter a list of tuples by items at given index and convert them into a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like below:

```
Lista = [('amazon', 'Amazon', 1.0), 
         ('amazon', 'Alexa', 0.8), 
         ('amazon', 'microsoft', 0.6), 
         ('amazon', 'Amazon Pay', 0.7), 
         ('amazon', 'Prime', 0.4),
         ('alien', 'jack' , 0.0), 
         ('alien', 'dell', 0.6),
         ('alien', 'apple', 0.0),
         ('alien', 'orange', 0.0),
         ('alien', 'fig', 0.0)]
```

Now I want to perform a basic check to see which tuples have the last value greater than 0.0 and then convert the resulting tuples into a dict of lists:

```
new_words = {'amazon': ['Amazon', 'Alexa', 'microsoft', 'Amazon Pay', 'Prime'],
             'alien': ['dell']}
```

How would I do it?

Comment: Related: [Converting a list of tuples into a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/261655/7851470)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have the desired result in a dictionary as dictionaries don't contain duplicate keys (similar to a normal English dictionary: where the words might spell the same but there are differences in pronunciation).

The desired result can be stored again into a list.

```
newDict = {}
result = []

Lista =[('amazon', 'Amazon', 1.0), ('amazon', 'Alexa', 0.8), ('amazon', 'microsoft', 0.6), ('amazon', 'Amazon Pay', 0.7), ('amazon', 'Prime', 0.4),('alien', 'jack' , 0.0), ('alien', 'dell', 0.6), ('alien', 'apple', 0.0), ('alien', 'orange', 0.0), ('alien', 'fig', 0.0)]

for items in Lista:
    if items[2] > 0.0:
        newDict[items[0]] = items[1]
        result.append(newDict)
        newDict = {}

print result
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. While your solution works for me. I wanted to know why the newDict ={} has been called again after the line `result.append(newDict)`

Comment: Also, it would be great if you could provide me the output in this format `{'amazon': ['Amazon', 'Alexa', 'microsoft', 'Amazon Pay', 'Prime'],
 'alien': ['dell']}` like @jan's solution

Comment: If we don't empty the dictionary, then while executing the next iteration in the loop the new item will be appended to the dictionary and we don't want that.
I'm not sure if I explained it perfectly so, please try without that line and you'll know what I mean.

@jan has already provided the solution, right?
If you need any improvements on that, please elaborate and we'll see how that can be achieved.

Comment: Thanks Rahul for the explanation. I get it now. Jan's solution is not working for me for some reason but your solution is working, Is there a way you could tweak your code to provide Jan's output . Like this `{'amazon': ['Amazon', 'Alexa', 'microsoft', 'Amazon Pay', 'Prime'], 'alien': ['dell']}`

Answer (score 2):

You most likely want a dictionary of lists. Here's one approach using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

{k:[i[1] for i in list(v) if i[2]>0.] for k,v in groupby(Lista, key=itemgetter(0))}

{'amazon': ['Amazon', 'Alexa', 'microsoft', 'Amazon Pay', 'Prime'],
 'alien': ['dell']}
```

---

*Note*: This only works if equal keys are consecutive

Comment: This only works if the duplicate keys are consecutive, so you'd need to sort first if they aren't.

Comment: Yes, added a warning @interjay

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

Lista =[('amazon', 'Amazon', 1.0), ('amazon', 'Alexa', 0.8), ('amazon', 'microsoft', 0.6), ('amazon', 'Amazon Pay', 0.7), ('amazon', 'Prime', 0.4),('alien', 'jack' , 0.0), ('alien', 'dell', 0.6), ('alien', 'apple', 0.0), ('alien', 'orange', 0.0), ('alien', 'fig', 0.0)]

dct = defaultdict(list)

for item in Lista:
    key, value, score = item
    if score > 0.0:
        dct[key].append(value)

print(dct)
```

Which yields

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
    'alien': ['dell'], 
    'amazon': ['Amazon', 'Alexa', 'microsoft', 'Amazon Pay', 'Prime']
})
```

Your initial request - having a dictionary with multiple identical keys - is not possible in `Python`.

Comment: The line `dct = defaultdict(list)` throws an error  " first argument must be callable or None"

Comment: @venkatttaknev: The error comes from the fact that you called a variable `list` somewhere, e.g. `list = 123` which shadows the builtin function `list()`. Otherwise the code works flawlessly.