# How to get the results in a dictionary of lists format

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, key-value

I have the following code

```
newDict = {}
result = []

Lista =[('amazon', 'Amazon', 1.0), ('amazon', 'Alexa', 0.8), ('amazon', 'microsoft', 0.6), ('amazon', 'Amazon Pay', 0.7), ('amazon', 'Prime', 0.4),('alien', 'jack' , 0.0), ('alien', 'dell', 0.6), ('alien', 'apple', 0.0), ('alien', 'orange', 0.0), ('alien', 'fig', 0.0)]

for items in Lista:
    if items[2] > 0.0:
        newDict[items[0]] = items[1]
        result.append(newDict)
        newDict = {}

print (result)
```

This gives the output

```
[{'amazon': 'Amazon'}, {'amazon': 'Alexa'}, {'amazon': 'microsoft'}, {'amazon': 'Amazon Pay'}, {'amazon': 'Prime'}, {'alien': 'dell'}]
```

How do I get the output in the below format by just making minimum changes in the above code.

Desired output

```
{'amazon': ['Amazon', 'Alexa', 'microsoft', 'Amazon Pay', 'Prime'], 'alien': ['dell']}
```

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? [How to convert a list having multiple values into a dictionary of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59287573/7851470)

Comment: No, it did not. hence this question. defaultdict did not work for me and the solution highlighted in my current question gave a different format.

Comment: 1) "defaultdict did not work for me" - I don't think that the fact that solutions on your previous question didn't work for you is a valid reason to post the question again. You should address it in comments or in an edit to your previous question. 2) "the solution highlighted in my current question gave a different format"  - You can have 100 not working solutions, but it doesn't mean that you should post 100 questions asking for the same thing.

Comment: Okay point taken. Will refrain going forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all since you want to have your output to be a `dict` you shouldn't initiate it as `list`. In our loop instead of appending new `dict` to our `result` we should create new `list` for each individual `key` to append new items to it later on. Also variable names shouldn't be uppercase (classes should be named that way), so `Lista` could be renamed to let's say to `my_list`.

```
my_list = [('amazon', 'Amazon', 1.0), ('amazon', 'Alexa', 0.8), ('amazon', 'microsoft', 0.6), ('amazon', 'Amazon Pay', 0.7), ('amazon', 'Prime', 0.4),('alien', 'jack' , 0.0), ('alien', 'dell', 0.6), ('alien', 'apple', 0.0), ('alien', 'orange', 0.0), ('alien', 'fig', 0.0)]
result = {}

for items in my_list:
    if items[2] > 0:
        if items[0] not in result:
            result[items[0]] = [items[1]]
        else:
            result[items[0]].append(items[1])
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'amazon': ['Amazon', 'Alexa', 'microsoft', 'Amazon Pay', 'Prime'], 'alien': ['dell']}
```

Comment: "In our loop instead of appending new dict to our result we should create new list for each individual key to append new items to it later on." . Can you please elaborate on this by giving a code example . Thanks.

Comment: It's code between last `if` and `else` in my answer.

Comment: Ignoring all the above for loop and if conditions. how to just convert this  `[{'amazon': 'Amazon'}, {'amazon': 'Alexa'}, {'amazon': 'microsoft'}, {'amazon': 'Amazon Pay'}, {'amazon': 'Prime'}, {'alien': 'dell'}]` to this format `{'amazon': ['Amazon', 'Alexa', 'microsoft', 'Amazon Pay', 'Prime'], 'alien': ['dell']}`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using dictionary comprehension:

```
Lista =[('amazon', 'Amazon', 1.0), ('amazon', 'Alexa', 0.8), ('amazon', 'microsoft', 0.6), ('amazon', 'Amazon Pay', 0.7), ('amazon', 'Prime', 0.4),('alien', 'jack' , 0.0), ('alien', 'dell', 0.6), ('alien', 'apple', 0.0), ('alien', 'orange', 0.0), ('alien', 'fig', 0.0)]
newDict = {k[0]:[i[1] for i in Lista if i[0] == k[0] and i[2] > 0] for k in Lista}
print(newDict)
```

Output:

```
{'amazon': ['Amazon', 'Alexa', 'microsoft', 'Amazon Pay', 'Prime'], 'alien': ['dell']}
```

Comment: That's computationally very expensive, its quadratic time Ɵ(n^2) just to squash things in one line.

Answer (score 1):

If you fancy using defaultdict in python.

```
from collections import defaultdict

newDict = defaultdict(list)

Lista =[('amazon', 'Amazon', 1.0), ('amazon', 'Alexa', 0.8), ('amazon', 'microsoft', 0.6), ('amazon', 'Amazon Pay', 0.7), ('amazon', 'Prime', 0.4),('alien', 'jack' , 0.0), ('alien', 'dell', 0.6), ('alien', 'apple', 0.0), ('alien', 'orange', 0.0), ('alien', 'fig', 0.0)]

for items in Lista:
    if items[2] > 0.0:
        newDict[items[0]] += [items[1]]


print (newDict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(Lista)

df[df[2] >0].groupby(0)[1].agg(list).to_dict()
```

output

```
{'alien': ['dell'],
 'amazon': ['Amazon', 'Alexa', 'microsoft', 'Amazon Pay', 'Prime']}
```